# RegEx issue in JavaScript Function - Not replacing anything

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, replace

Plan A: it's such a simple function... it's ridiculous, really. I'm either totally misunderstanding how RegEx works with string replacement, or I'm making another stupid mistake that I just can't pinpoint.

```
    function returnFloat(str){
        console.log(str.replace(/$,)( /g,""));
    }
```

but when I call it:

```
    returnFloat("($ 51,453,042.21)")
    >>> ($ 51,453,042.21)
```

It's my understanding that my regular expression should remove all occurrences of the dollar sign, the comma, and the parentheses. I've read through at least 10 different posts of similar issues (most people had the regex as a string or an invalid regex, but I don't think that applies here) without any changes resolving my issues.

My plan B is ugly:

```
            str = str.replace("$", "");
            str = str.replace(",", "");
            str = str.replace(",", "");
            str = str.replace(" ", "");
            str = str.replace("(", "");
            str = str.replace(")", "");
            console.log(str);
```

Comment: You are testing for a sequence of characters that must occur exactly like that while `$` has a special meaning. You want `/[$,)( ]/`, or why not `/\D+/`

Comment: well the reg exp is not really valid either..... Code should not even run. The parenthesis and dollarsign need escaped.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain things in RegEx that are considered special regex characters, which include the characters `$`, `(` and `)`. You need to escape them (and put them in a character set or bitwise or grouping) if you want to search for them exactly. Otherwise [Your Regex makes no sense to an interpreter](https://regex101.com/r/jEz9j8/1)

```js
function toFloat(str){
  return str.replace(/[\$,\(\)]/g,'');
}

console.log(toFloat('($1,234,567.90'));
```

Please note that this does *not* conver this string to a float, if you tried to do `toFloat('($1,234,567.90)')+10 you would get '1234568.9010'.` You would need to call the `parseFloat()` function.

Comment: There's no need to escape `$`, `(`, or `)` in a character class.

Comment: I've had issue with it before, so I do it now out of habit

Comment: Unlike everything else, I was aware that this does not parse to float. It also does not negate the number encapsulated by parentheses (financial format) as it should. I didn't want to proceed without at least getting this down first. I appreciate your help.

Comment: All due respect, I have ~15 years of JS experience, never once ran into an implementation of regex so broken it failed to handle `$`, `(`, or `)` in a character class correctly.

Comment: I also have ~15 years of Javascript experience, and I've run into issues with it before. considering it doesn't do any harm, _meh_

Comment: @Jhecht: Point to a bug report? Surely you reported the bug when you found it?

Comment: I'm unsure why you care so much about it. If you don't like them, then don't use them.

Comment: I don't, particularly. I *do* care about combating programming-as-magic, which is not useful to anyone, and not spreading misinformation. This particular misinformation is mostly harmless, granted. But unless you can point to a significant implementation in the wild that gets this wrong, pointless escapes are just that: Pointless.

Answer (score 1):

the `$` character means end of line, try:

```
console.log(str.replace(/[\$,)( ]/g,""));
```

Comment: No need to escape `$` inside a character class. Separately: "try" is not an adequate decription. Say **what** you did, and why. (Particularly since your first answer didn't do the above at all, and only got edited in after trincot pointed it out in a comment on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your replacement as `.replace(/[$,)( ]/g, "")`.

However, if you want to remove all letters that are not digit or dot,
and easier way exists:

```
.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
```

Here `\d` means digit (0 .. 9),
and `[^\d.]` means "not any of the symbols within the `[...]`",
in this case not a digit and not a dot.

Comment: Would I need to escape the period as well? Isn't it a wildcard?

Comment: @Jeesubmunu you don't need to escape the `.` inside a character class `[...]`

Answer (score -1):

if i understand correctly you want to have this list : 51,453,042.21

> What you need are character classes. In that, you've only to worry about the ], \ and - characters (and ^ if you're placing it straight after the beginning of the character class "[" ).
>   **Syntax: [characters] where characters is a list with characters to be drop( in your case $() ).**
>   The **g** means Global, and causes the replace call to replace all matches, not just the first one.

```
var myString = '($ 51,453,042.21)';
console.log(myString.replace(/[$()]/g, "")); //51,453,042.21
```

if you want to delete ','

```
var myString = '($ 51,453,042.21)';
console.log(myString.replace(/[$(),]/g, "")); //51453042.21
```

Comment: "try this" is not an answer. Say **what** you did, and **why**. Separately: This answer has already been posted, except that the posted version doesn't mysteriously drop `,` and space from the character class.